# is the array/vector of pointers can delete the pointer auto?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
std::vector<Object *> pVector;
```

when out of scope, is the array/vector of pointers can delete every pointer element automatically? or must delete the every object manually?

So if can I think that:  if the vector/array store no-pointer elements, it will call deconstructor automatically? but if stored pointers, it should delete elements manually?

Answer (score 2):

`vector` properly destroys objects stored *IN* the vector.  The destructor will be called.  If you have a vector of pointers, then this means the pointer's own destructor (and not what it points to).

The destructor for a raw pointer does nothing.  This is what you want if you have a non-owning pointer to an object that another part of the program will destroy.

The destructor for a smart pointer does whatever is necessary to make sure the object gets freed at the right time.  For `unique_ptr`, that's right now.  For `shared_ptr`, it's whenever the reference count hits zero.

Use the right kind of pointer, and trust vector to trigger the behavior associated with that pointer when the element is erased.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `vector` will only delete the memory it holds, which is memory to hold the pointers - effectively, it'll be an array of some size such as:

```
Object **array = new Object*[size];
```

When the destructor is called, all that gets deleted is this array store:

```
delete[] array;
```

As you can see, this will not free whatever those pointers are pointing to. This is why you should use a `vector` of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` as opposed to raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

When the std::vector is destroyed, it calls the `Object *` destructor not the `Object` so only the pointer to the memory is destroyed.

You should use either smart pointers `(std::shared_ptr<Object> or std::unique_ptr<Object>)`, either `boost::ptr_vector<Object>` which will manage memory for you.